# Calculate an integral on an unlimited interval

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have some trouble solving:

$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(x+1)}dx
$$
what I know is that the integral is equal to:
$$
\log(x) - \log(x+1) = \log\left(\frac{x}{x + 1}\right) \Big|_1^\infty
$$
then I found a method which says to limit the function and use the leiblith formula:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\Big|_1^t
$$
Is this method the right method? I got a $\log(\frac{1}{2})$ as a result but wolfram|Alpha says it is $\log(2)$

Answer (score 4):

You should have gotten $$0-\log(1/2) = -\log(1/2) = \log[(1/2)^{(-1)}] =  \log(2)$$

Comment: Short and accurate answer!

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\Big|_1^t  \\=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\log\left(\frac{t}{t+1}\right) - \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ =\log(1) - \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0 - (-\log(2)) = \log(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

You have a prefix error.

The result you will get is $-\log(1/2)$ instead of $\log(1/2)$. Now note that $-\log(1/2) = \log(2)$